# Default Browser in Windows 10... still Edge (and the search engine is still Bing)

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, windows-search

I have Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.17134 Build 17134), and I have been set the default browser in "default apps" to "Google Chrome".
I also have changed the search engine to Google.

However, when I press "Windows" button and I start typing, say "Céline"
[image]

There is always "Bing" and "Edge" that are opening and searching... where the hek I can change this to use my browser ?

I recall that for the EU citizens there is a way to [complain to the anti-monopoly commission](https://ec.europa.eu/info/departments/informatics_en#contact) on the Microsoft practices to impose its products with the Windows OS.

Comment: Searching on the Start Menu is basically searching using Microsoft Assistant Cortana... and I'd quite sure Cortana will default to Edge/Bing as default.. and I don't know if you can change that. There are some 3rd party apps that claims it can do it.. but I can't recommend any. Your best workaround is to open Chrome and then do the search from within Chrome.

Comment: The issue is indeed that Cortana uses bing by default: https://www.howtogeek.com/226638/make-the-windows-10-start-menu-and-cortana-search-google-instead-of-bing/

Comment: I disabled and I don't want to use Cortana.

Comment: Cortana is the Search Engine while you have disabled the voice assistance the web functionality is still Cortana.  Of course you made no mention of Cortana being disabled in your question body.

Comment: because there's any way of really disable Cortana. I just disabled the voice assistant, and other things I could via the registry, but when you press Win key it seems that is cortana who controls

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it seems there is no "official" way to do it, via the Microsoft (default) utils.

**Cortana** will **always** launch **Bing** searches in the **Edge** browser. You used to be able to pick which browser you wanted to search in, but Microsoft closed this possibility.

At least for the EU this does not correspond to the European Antitrust current legislation and directives.

However, [is seems there are a third-party app called EdgeDeflector that could "redirect" the Bing searches to Google](https://www.howtogeek.com/226638/make-the-windows-10-start-menu-and-cortana-search-google-instead-of-bing/)....

Comment: It won’t be possible until at least 1903 when Cortana function is rumored to be optional

Comment: 1903 will be the first feature update of 2019.  It is expected to separate search from Cortana.  Using the default browser isn’t a feature of Cortana.